# Displaying Zoom and Center on OpenSeadragon

Tags: seadragon, openseadragon

I'm using OpenSeaDragon for the first time and I'm trying to display to the console zoom level and Viewport center.

Now I found out how to display coordinates on click ([Openseadragon image cordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417287/openseadragon-image-cordinates)), but I'm having trouble w/ zoom and center. From looking at the API doc, I'm thinking that I need to use getCenter and getZoom of method Viewport, but syntactically I'm lost. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

So after some help, here's the code I ended up using to get click coordinates as well as zoom and center (in image coordinates):

```
viewer.addHandler('canvas-click', function(target, info) {
    var viewportPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(info.position);
    var imagePoint = viewer.viewport.viewportToImageCoordinates(viewportPoint.x, viewportPoint.y);
    console.log(imagePoint.x, imagePoint.y);
    console.log(viewer.viewport.getZoom());
    var viewportCenter = viewer.viewport.getCenter();
    var imageCenter = viewer.viewport.viewportToImageCoordinates(viewportCenter.x, viewportCenter.y);
    console.log(imageCenter.x, imageCenter.y);
});
```

Comment: Be careful, there have been changes in newer versions of OSD. The `info` argument will be undefined now. See this thread, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18417287/981694

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. If your viewer is called `viewer`, you would do `viewer.viewport.getZoom()` for instance.

The viewport has a number of other coordinate conversion methods:

http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/symbols/OpenSeadragon.Viewport.html

...and there's also a plugin that provides even more, if you need:

https://github.com/msalsbery/openseadragonimaginghelper